# How to create initial population and obtain best solution

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, evolutionary-algorithm

This would be a trivial question to pros but difficult for a newbie like me.
Evolutionary Algorithm - I am trying to generate the initial population for a system with a given  objective function and 3 bounded constraints. 
Issue is I don't know the solver to use and their respective codes. I have gone through some of the matlab documentations but cannot find much info.

Any help or procedure whatsoever would be appreciated.

OBJECTIVE FUNCTION:

```
ZETA(i) = -SIG(i) ./(sqrt(SIG(i).^2 + OMG(i).^2));
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= K <= 50
0.1 <= T1 <= 1
0.01 <= T2 <= 0.2
```

K, T1, T2 - are variables used in calculating ZETA, SIG, OMG and are MATRICES.

I have created a function that does the matrix computation to obtain the real and imaginary values of the matrix with is SIG and OMG. Now I am stuck trying to proceed to creating an EA.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `K`, `T1` and `T2` being used anywhere. However, if you are looking for a starting position, why not some arbitrary valid numbers: `K=25, T1 = 0.5, T2=0.1`. For the optimization, try looking into [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)